# react router and passport.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, passport.js

I have a react app and I'm trying to implement passport.js for github authentication.

Following the passport.js docs, I have set up an express server to handle the authentication on the backend. I have also set up the secret key from Github that should get this working.

My main question is, how can I use react router/routes to GET/POST to the express server router?

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Route from "react-router-dom/Route";

...

class App extends Component {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">

      <Link to="/auth/github">Login using Github (react route)</Link>

      <Route
        path="/auth/github" exact
        render={() => {
          return <h1>Logging In Using GitHub</h1>;
        }}
      />

    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
}
```

index.js

```
const app = express();
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

...

app.get("/auth/github",
  passport.authenticate("github", { scope: ["repo"] }),

  function(req, res) {
    res.send("logging in through github");
  }
);

app.get("/auth/github/redirect",
  passport.authenticate("github", { failureRedirect: "/" }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect("/");
  }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

it's probably a good idea to have a specific sub-path that indicates that the request is meant for your server instead of your frontend - I typically use `/api/...` for these routes.

Following,

> how can I use react router/routes to GET/POST to the express server router

you don't. You let your web server handle it. Links to these paths should be hard redirects, not `ReactRouter.Link` links (use `<a href="..."/>`).

If you're using webpack, you'll want to set up the devServer to forward these requests to your backend - I think the syntax is

```
proxy: {
  '/api': {
    target: 'http://localhost:3000/api',
    secure: false
  }
}
```

and then, in production, make sure that your webserver is "proxying" these requests to your server (and everything else just serves your bundle).